# how to set auto increment column value with condition

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I have table like this:

```
value nextValue
1     2
2     3
3     20
20    21
21    22
22    23
23    NULL
```

Value is ordered ASC, nextValue is next row Value.
requirement is group by with condition nextValue-value>10, and count how many values in different groups.

For example, there should be two groups `(1,2,3)` and `(20,21,22,23)`, first group count is 3, the second group count is 4.

I'm trying to mark each group with unique number, so I could group by these marked nums

```
value nextValue mark
1     2         1
2     3         1
3     20        1
20    21        2
21    22        2
22    23        2
23    NULL      2
```

But I don't know how to write mark column, I need an autocrement variable when `nextValue-value>10`.
Can I make it happen in Hive? Or there's better solution for the requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use a cumulative sum.  The idea is to set a flag when `next_value - value > 10`.  This identifies the groups.  So, this query adds a group number:

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when nextvalue > value + 10 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by value desc) as mark
from t
order by value;
```

You might not find this solution satisfying, because the numbering is in descending order.  So, a bit more arithmetic fixes that:

```
select t.*,
       (sum(case when nextvalue > value + 10 then 1 else 0 end) over () + 1 -
        sum(case when nextvalue > value + 10 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by value desc)
       ) as mark
from t
order by value;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=623fa54130e1eae25db9ff07817d6444) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate previous value, then calculate new_group_flag if value-prev_value >10, then calculate cumulative sum of new_group_flag to get group number (mark). Finally you can calculate group count using analytics function or group-by (in my example analytics count is used to show you the full dataset with all intermediate calculations). See comments in the code.

Demo:

```
with your_data as (--use your table instead of this
select stack(10, --the number of tuples generated
1  ,  
2  ,  
3  ,  
20 ,  
21 ,  
22 ,  
23 ,  
40 ,
41 ,
42
) as value
)

select --4. Calculate group count, etc, etc
       value, prev_value, new_group_flag, group_number, 
       count(*) over(partition by group_number) as group_count
from
(
select --3. Calculate cumulative sum of new group flag to get group number
       value, prev_value, new_group_flag, 
       sum(new_group_flag) over(order by value rows between unbounded preceding and current row)+1 as group_number
from
(
select --2. calculate new_group_flag
       value, prev_value, case when value-prev_value >10 then 1 else 0 end as new_group_flag
from
(
select  --1 Calculate previous value
      value, lag(value) over(order by value) prev_value
  from your_data
)s
)s
)s
```

Result:

```
value  prev_value  new_group_flag  group_number   group_count
1       \N           0              1              3
2       1            0              1              3
3       2            0              1              3
20      3            1              2              4
21      20           0              2              4
22      21           0              2              4
23      22           0              2              4
40      23           1              3              3
41      40           0              3              3
42      41           0              3              3
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me
It needs "rows between unbounded preceding and current row" in my case.

```
select t.*,
       sum(case when nextvalue > value + 10 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by value desc rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as mark
from t
order by value;
```